# Plotting several Y values vs X

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have to plot two charts. The problem:

```
f1 = x1*(x2-1)
f2 = x1^2+x2^2
```

Restrictions:

```
x2 <= x1
x1 <= x2*4
0 <= x1 <= 1
0 <= x2 <= 1
```

I have to draw all possible values in two charts. 1 - x1 vs x2; 2 - f1 vs f2.
For restrictions x2<=x1 and x1<=x2*4 i've came up with `x2<=x1<=x2*4` so it's easier to code.

I've tried creating a small code which would create x1 and x2, but with no luck unfortunately.

```
x1 = []
for n in range(1,1000,1):
   x1.append(n/1000) #Couldn't find a better solution to create a list between 0 and 1

pValues11 = []
for n in range(1,10000,1):
   pValues11.append(n/10000)

x2 = []
for index,n in enumerate(x1):
   x2.append([])
   for m in pValues11:
      if n <= m and m <= 4*n:
        x2[index].append(m)
```

x2 creates a list of list while x1 is like an indexing. However if i try to plot them:

```
plt.plot(x1,x2,'bo')
plt.show()
```

I recieve `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

All in all, I think it's a messy way to solve this problem, however I have no idea how to do it cleanly.

The result should look like this, my classmate's:

[image]

Comment: I suggest getting familiar with `numpy`. You can then call `numpy.linspace(0,1,1000)` to generate `x1`, for example (although that will also contain `1000`). Same goes for `pValues11`. I'm not sure what you actually want to achieve, but you can convert `x2` to a `numpy` 2d array (i.e. matrix), and plot each column of `x2` versus `x1`: `plot(x1,numpy.array(x2))`. For all this you have to `import numpy` first. I believe your current code generates a huge bunch of zeros, since `python` uses integer division by default, so `999/1000==0`.

Comment: For clarification what i want to achieve - http://i.imgur.com/FlRNgSF.jpg

Comment: Are you sure there aren't anymore restrictions? Or that your specification is correct? First you're saying `x2<x1<4x2`, then `x2<4x1<4x2`.

Comment: `x2 <= x1; x1 <= 4x2` is the specifications ins the problem. I rearranged it to be `x2<=4x1<=4x2` as it doesn't matter in my view. x2 has to be equal or less than x1 and x1 has to be equal or less than x2*4. Hmm... now that i've rewritten it, i start to think i might haved made a mistake.... Yeah, i think it had to be `x2<=x1<=4x2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution based on `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1=np.linspace(0,1,1000)
x2=np.linspace(0,1,1000)[:,None]

#f1=x1*(x2-1)
#f2=x1**2+x2**2

inds=(x2<=x1) & (x1<=4*x2)

x1new=(x1+np.zeros(x2.shape))[inds]
x2new=(x2+np.zeros(x1.shape))[inds]
#f1new=f1[inds]
#f2new=f2[inds]
f1new=x1new*(x2new-1)
f2new=x1new**2+x2new**2

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x1new,x2new)
plt.xlabel(r"$x_1$")
plt.ylabel(r"$x_2$")

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(f1new,f2new)
plt.xlabel(r"$f_1$")
plt.ylabel(r"$f_2$")

plt.show()
```

This will essentially generate a 2d mesh of `x1`,`x2` values, then check each pair against the conditions. Those which fail the test are discarded, so we keep only the correct `x1`,`x2`,`f1`,`f2` values. Then we just plot them.

My output:

[image: x2 vs x1] [image: f2 vs f1]

Your expected output:

[image: expected]

The differences arise from the fact that the expected output is plotted up to `x2=0.5`, and I used the full range up to `x2=1`.

Comment: Thanks! Damn it's elegant